# How to cancel a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player, seekbar

I am trying to make a media player which has a `seekbar`.
As the `seekbar` should stop progress when pause is pressed or stop is pressed. I want to stop the thread accordingly. Moreover when back is pressed I want to cancel the thread again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop a java thread gracefully ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully)

Comment: @NLV Thread.suspend is deprecated, because it won't release any locks the thread holds

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean running = true;
final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(running){
                 //Your code
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //handler code

    }
});
t.start();
```

defining a "running" boolean will manage when the thread will execute its code, when you set running to false the seekbar will stop without interrupting or killing the thread.