# Problem with while stop thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying  to stop a thread. while stopping my thread i got thread interrupted  exception.

What I can do if thread throw interrupted exception. should i catch it and do nothing or do i need to do  anything?

Comment: "Its depends" is my first reaction. Some more context please?

Comment: Take a look at this Brian Goetz article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You should not 'just stop' a thread. The thing I mostly do is create a public (perhaps static) variable in the Thread's class that indicates when the thread should stop. So something like a declaration of

```
public volatile bool shouldStop = false;
```

Then, at the end of every cycle of your thread, you could check if you need to quit (break from the while-loop or something).

Threads can be very annoying to handle! Calling interrupt/stop functions on just a thread itself is possible, but mostly unwanted.

Comment: to me, it makes more sense to just check the thread's interrupted state (i.e. `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`)

Comment: It might be better to make that a _volatile_ boolean.

Comment: Why is calling interrupt unwanted? It's the proper mechanism to interrupt a waiting thread.

Comment: If the code is throwing an InterruptedException, then it is blocking on something.  The only way to cancel the blocking is to interrupt the thread.  If it is an operation that will timeout or complete, then the code would have to wait for that to happen before it can check the shouldStop flag, which may not be acceptable

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason .stop() and .suspend() were deprecated and should not be used. This article is relevant:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Also I quote the Javadocs:

> Deprecated. This method is inherently
>   unsafe. Stopping a thread with
>   Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of
>   the monitors that it has locked (as a
>   natural consequence of the unchecked
>   ThreadDeath exception propagating up
>   the stack). If any of the objects
>   previously protected by these monitors
>   were in an inconsistent state, the
>   damaged objects become visible to
>   other threads, potentially resulting
>   in arbitrary behavior. Many uses of
>   stop should be replaced by code that
>   simply modifies some variable to
>   indicate that the target thread should
>   stop running. The target thread should
>   check this variable regularly, and
>   return from its run method in an
>   orderly fashion if the variable
>   indicates that it is to stop running.
>   If the target thread waits for long
>   periods (on a condition variable, for
>   example), the interrupt method should
>   be used to interrupt the wait. For
>   more information, see Why are
>   Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and
>   Thread.resume Deprecated?.

You should find some way (whether by some shared variable or otherwise) to synchronise your threads so the thread can end itself.

Comment: This is a good point, but I don't think OP is using .stop(). Otherwise, they wouldn't be getting the InterruptedException.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs. You can (for example) do something like this:

```
public void run() {
    try {
         // do thread stuff
    } catch(ThreadInterruptedException ex) {
         // close gracefully what needed to be closed
    }
}
```

But the [stop method is deprecated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29). So a better solution is to put some boolean variable to indicate whether the thread should stop or not and provide a method to change it in order to stop the thread (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully) for example).