# Create 2 threads and communicate between them

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

I want to make a background task in one thread and send information from that thread to another thread which runs the main program and update the information each period of time.

Thread1:

```
public void doTask()
{
    // ...
    someData = ...;
}
```

Thread2:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        new MainFrame(someData);
    }
});
```

How could I achieve this in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I using [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)/[ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), output from these methods starting [java.swing.Action](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) (create a new EDT if doesn't exists),

or you can test that For EDT

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {...
```

both ways for your Wratever sould be always in EDT, I vote for wraps output to the GUI into `Action`

Comment: Thanks man. I'm really not fimiliar with using threads or even Java Concurrency API, could you please provide a very simple example that achieves what I'm looking for? :)

Comment: yes here is my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036509/how-do-i-simulate-a-buffered-peripheral-device-with-swingworker/7049095#comment-8432327, made just by my enjoy, look here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-thread , with intention to starting MultiThreading wrapped into SwingWorker, should be required for all of methods implements <?>Future, not only SwingWorker, in all cases don't forget to implements PropertyChangeListener for listening statuses from Future

Comment: This example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-thread was very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: glad to helps, that was my nightMare, but really you have to redirect your thanks to @trashgod

Comment: +1 for `SwingWorker`, a `RunnableFuture` that is convenient if the destination thread is the EDT. There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Java Concurrency API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Usage of `BlockingQueue`s, `Future<>` will help you.

Note: This is a classic producer-consumer problem. This can be achieved having a shared queue to hold data where one thread will push data into the queue and the othe will consume the data. Proper synchronisation is needed to achieve a correct solution. `BlockingQueue` implementations like `LinkedBlockingQueue` will be helpful.

Update: Part of you problem [the consumer] can be derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301186/how-to-stop-a-thread-in-java-and-let-the-same-thread-to-do-another-thing/6302642#6302642) answer of mine. But this solution uses the simpler `wait`-`notify` approach.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example if possible? :)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have a direct mechanism for a specific thread to send a message to another SPECIFIC thread.

But there are indirect ways of achieving this though. For example, you can define a message queue object on one thread and then pass a reference to that queue to the second thread. The second thread can insert message objects into this queue; and the first thread can keep polling the queue to get itself alerted to new messages.

Also answered in this thread

[Communicating between two threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916398/communicating-between-2-threads)

The above link has some sample (pseudo) code.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe an overengineered aproach for this case, but nonetheless you could use [EventBus](http://eventbus.org/) - each Thread could publish and be subsrcibed to events.

An example is [here](http://bwinterberg.blogspot.com/2009/05/eventbus-library.html).