# I was searching for stopping java thread gracefully and found that, but I cannot know how to check example of this situation

Tags: java, thread-safety

This is good example of stopping thread.
[How to stop a java thread gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully)
But when I try to check this example I received infinite loop.

This is my code:

```
public class Num {

    public void crash(ManualStopping t1) {
        t1.stopMe();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Num num = new Num();
        ManualStopping t1 = new ManualStopping();
        t1.run();
        System.out.println("Main thread");
        num.crash(t1);
    }
}
```

```
class ManualStopping extends Thread {

    volatile boolean finished = false;
    public void stopMe() {
        finished = true;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!finished) {
            System.out.println("I'm alive");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good lesson for me:
run() method does not create new thread it just execute run method. For creating new thread you should invoke start() method on a Thread instance 
Thanks for all)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to `start` your thread - not `run` it. By calling run, you are just making a normal method call, not running a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code calls the `stopMe` method on `ManualStopping`. `isInterrupted()` is a test that doesn't change the state of the thread. And as @DaveHowes points out, you don't even start a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

`t1.run();`  Change it to `t1.start()`.

Whats happening is that the thread you intend to spawn is not actually running as a separate thread. Instead the loop

`while(!finished){         System.out.println("I'm alive");     }`

is running on the main thread and your code `num.crash(t1);` never actually gets invoked. This is causing the infinite loop.