# Shut down a single thread running

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown

Suppose during my running I would like to shutdown a single thread **gracefully!**

I don't want to use `Thread.stop()` nor `Thread.destroy()` due to their unsafe behavior.

Note: I'm familiar with using `ExecutorService.shutdown()` option. 
But I would like to know the other way to implement.

Comment: `ExecutorService.shutdown()` does not shut down the running threads - it merely says that the executor won't accept new tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to stop a thread is to call `thread.interrupt();`. To make it work, you need to make sure you thread responds to interruption, for example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run {
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        //your code here
    }
}});
t.start();
t.interrupt();
```

This only works if the condition is checked regularly. Note that you can delegate the interruption mechanism to interruptible methods (typically I/O, blocking queues, sleep/wait provide methods that can block until they are interrupted).

Note: In this example, you can also use:

```
    while(!interrupted()) {
        //your code here
    }
```

`interrupted()` does the same thing as `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` except that the interrupted flag is reset. Since it is your thread, it does not matter.

Comment: One advantage of `interrupted()` is that it is static, so less code can be involved: `while (!interrupted()) { ... }`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I remember we've had this discussion ;-)

Comment: I'm actually referring to that discussion (hence no intro); I just present a new conclusion :)

Comment: Merci :) Just one note: I'm implying a static import that will be necessary unless one `extends Thread`. Since your first example has an explicit qualification of `currentThread`, this may lead to a wrong conclusion.

Comment: But what if the condition is not checked regularly. I don't want to be depend on Thread.isInterrupted();

Comment: @EldarDamari I'm not sure I understand your question: it is up to you how often you check the condition...

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the `run()` method of the thread terminate for some reason. How you achieve this depends on *what the thread does*.

- If the thread is looping, you can stop it by raising a flag (checked by the condition of the loop).
- If the thread is waiting over a `Socket` or any other stream, just close the stream.
- If the thread is blocked on a call that can throw an `InterruptedException`, you can `interrupt()` the thread and ignore the exception.
- If the thread is consuming the elements of a blocking queue, use the *poison pill* method, which means putting on the queue an element that just means "stop looping".

Comment: +1 but note that it is always preferred to use the built-in interruption mechanism instead of a custom flag. It has a good chance of composing better with other interruptible code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I still don't understand why the standard answer for those questions is always "use a boolean flag"...

Comment: @assylias I just googled it and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3461/ch2mt-57/index.html) seems to hold a partial answer: it used to be discouraged until everyone realized that all other interruption mechanisms are far worse.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Interesting finding!

Comment: Interesting discussion. So far, I've been using interrupt() only when the thread is blocked on a wait().

Comment: @gd1 Whenever you'd use a custom flag, just use the `interrupted` flag with the same local result + the extra benefit of having a chance to interrupt any other interruptible method.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `isStopped()`flag in your code. And the running thread should regularly check this flag to see if it should stop. Note that stopping a thread gracefully requires the running code to be written in a way that allows stopping.

[You can take a look at this question for some more detailed answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a loop inside your `run()` method of your `Thread` then one option would be that your loop checks for the value of a flag on every iteration.

You can set the flag from outside the code, such as your thread would stop executing before starting the next iteration.

Comment: The standard way to stop a thread is to call `thread.interrupt();`.