# Killing Thread without periodically checking alive status

Tags: java, multithreading

I am runnning `ExecutorService` to perform a heavy computation, however I don't want to pollute the algorithmic class/method code with runner operations, in this case I'd like to do periodical check if it should be terminated gracefully.

I tried to search for solutions, still with no success, what I concluded is that this is not possible because only the thread itself is allowed to "autokill himself".

So my question is, if there is any way to terminate the thread "outside" of the thread by invoking some forcefull atempt to kill the thread.

If not maybe the best solution is to use aspect and intercept each iteration by adding a kill status check ?

Comment: Can't you interrupt the thread?

Comment: Yeah, check a flag. Perhaps you can wrap the calculation code in another class that interfaces with the scheduling logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop a java thread gracefully?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `thread.interrupt()`. This can cause thread to exit if it "respects" interruptions. For example if thread is blocked on IO or on `wait()` or on `sleep()` `InterruptedExcption` will be thrown. However if it is "blocked" on busy loop that does not check `isInterrupted()` flag interruption will not work.

Other way to indeed kill the thread is to call deprecated method `stop()`. However this is the last possibility. This method is deprecated because it indeed kills threads immediately (like `kill -9`) that can cause resource leaks.

Bottom line: to be able to stop threads grecefully you have to write code that is ready for this and the standard solution is to respect thread interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

There sure is a way to forcefully terminate a thread: `Thread#stop`, but it is almost never advisable. Your idea with aspects seems quite fruitful, but if you have any sort of a main loop in your task, then consider replacing the loop with a series of submitted tasks where each task is one iteration. This will allow `ExecutorService#shutdown` to interrupt the processing. All state can be carried along in the instance of `Runnable` that is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the ExecutorService much. But reading the JavaDocs it appears that you submit a callable or runnable to the service. Those methods return a Future object which have a cancel method on it.

```
cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

Have you tried using that?

Answer (score 0):

The method thread.interrupt() stop the thread and you can call it outside the thread itself!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the original implementation, you could wrap the thread. I'm not very familar with Java, so I'm sorry for the obviously not compiling example:

```
class ThreadWrapper extends Thread {
    public ThreadWrapper(Thread t, TerminateCallback c) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        t.start(Thread.SYNCHRONOUS);
        c.done(this);
    }
}
```

You'd need to implement `TerminateCallback` yourself. I also assume there is a way to start a thread synchronously, `Thread.SYNCHRONOUS` is just a place holder. If this condition is fulfilled, I'm sure you can transfer it into valid code. :)

Comment: Me gets the feeling that I missunderstood the question. :)