# Can't get all AWT threads to close on exit

Tags: java, multithreading, join, awt, exit

I'm attempting to get my Java application to close, but threads are being left open.

When close is clicked using the default windows x button, everything shuts fine (probably due to EXIT_ON_CLOSE?)- but when I use a programmatic button, it hangs on thread.join().

Even worse, the window is disposed fine, so the user would think it's shut- yet there are several AWT threads that stay open. My main thread is waiting on a thread with an id of 20, but I have no idea how to get thread IDs.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's my exit code:

```
public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    frame.dispose();
    WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
    try {
        if (server != null) {
            server.exit();
        }
        client.exit();
        thread.join();
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }.start();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

and here are the threads open post-exit:

[image: threads-eclipse]

and here's the contents of my `run()` method:

```
public void run() {
    requestFocus();
    while (running) {
        getTimer().tick();
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - getTimer().getSecond() > 1000) {
            // every second, add a second, print fps and mod title with fps
            getTimer().accumulateSecond();
            //System.out.println(getTimer().returnFPS());
            frame.setTitle(title + "  |  " + getTimer().returnFPS());
            getTimer().resetTick();
            ticker++;
        }
        while (getTimer().getDelta() >= 1) {
            // every time delta goes greater than one, update and supertick
            update();
            getTimer().superTick();
        }
        if (getTimer().getFPS() > 100) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Sleeping failed: " + e);
            }
        } 
        render();
        if (ticker > 30) {
            ticker = 0;
            getTimer().hourTick();
        }

    }
    stop();
}
```

Comment: moving the `System.exit(0)` temporary thread above `join()` works to close it completely, but I doubt it's thread-safe?

Comment: please whats reason missing that here, could it be wrong,

Comment: Is the `run()` method you show in an *inner* `Thread` class within the same class as the `stop()` method above?  Are there any other calls within `run()` that invoke `synchronized` methods?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

After seeing more of your code, I'm pretty sure your problem is that you are calling `stop()` (which is `synchronized`) from one thread.  Inside `stop()`, you call `thread.join()`, which attempts to wait for the `thread` instance to finish its `run()` method.  Setting the `running` flag causes `run()` to exit its `while` loop, but the last line of code in the method is another call to `stop()`.  If this is the **same** `stop()` method you showed us, then you have a *deadlock*.

The `stop()` call inside your `run()` method will never be able to enter the method, because the first thread is still inside `stop()` and is waiting for `run()` to complete (which it never will, because it's waiting to be able to call and enter `stop()`).  Deadlock.

You will have to remove the call to `stop()` from within `run()`, or find another way to rework your code.

---

I wouldn't worry about identifying particular thread IDs.  Worry about letting all your threads complete properly.

First of all, `Thread#join()` does not **stop** a thread.  It waits for it to finish.  Something else you're doing must cause/allow the `thread` instance to complete its `run()` method.

The only thing I see that could possibly do this is setting

```
    running = false;
```

Is your `thread` object checking that flag inside its `run()` method?  For example:

```
public void run() {
    while (isRunning()) {

        // do some work
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

where `isRunning()` would return you the value of the `running` variable?

Now, I can't say without seeing more of your code.  However, you may have chosen to implement `isRunning()` like this:

```
public synchronized boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
}
```

If you did that, then there's a problem.  The main thread will acquire the lock in the `stop()` method you showed us.  Then it will get to the `thread.join()` call, at which point it starts waiting for the worker thread.  If the worker thread then calls `isRunning()` which is synchronized on the same lock, then `isRunning()` will block, because the lock is already held by virtue of the main thread being inside `stop()`.

The same basic problem could occur if the `thread` object is trying to call any other `synchronized` method **from the class whose code you showed us**.

Long story short, we'd need to see some more code (what is running in the thread represented by the `thread` variable).  But, you may have reached a deadlock here.

[Read more here about stopping a thread gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully)

Comment: The `run()` method checks `running` directly, and yes, the whole thing is whiled right inside it. I believe it's waiting on some subthread to close, but I can't identify any. There aren't many synchronized methods about, not too many resources that could become unsynced.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us that code (the code that runs inside the `run()` method passed to the `thread` object).  What you've shown is not enough to debug the problem, aside from the guess I already made.

Comment: @gossfunkel, if that's the same `stop()` method being called from `run()`, then that's your problem. `stop()` is `synchronized`, so `thread` will not be able to enter `stop()`, since another thread is already **inside** `stop()`, waiting at `thread.join()`.

Comment: sweet jesus, you're right. That was astonishingly stupid, terribly sorry! unfortunately, it's not solved the problem.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand.  Was it the same call to `stop()`?  If so, then that's a problem.  If you're still not seeing the thread die, then you **also** have another problem.  But, since we can't see the definitions of your other methods, it's hard to say what **else** might be wrong.

Comment: It looks like I have another problem! I dare say I'll just need to use the fix I have right now, and solve it properly when I can identify the problem.

Comment: @gossfunkel, please don't post questions and then decide you don't really need the solution.  That wastes the time of people who take time to help you (for free).

Comment: The need is still there, but there is no rush for a solution to be found. Thanks very much for the help, I was just saying that it didn't fix it, and that I could wait out learning the fix in the long run if the answer isn't readily available now.