# Stopping a Runnable while waiting for a connection in a while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops

I have a `Runnable` class which is waiting for a `Socket` connection. I want to add `JButton` that can cause it to stop waiting for the connection and come out of the loop.

Here is the loop

```
volatile boolean finished = false;

while (!finished) {
    System.out.println("Server Started....");
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();    // want to skip this line when the button is pressed
    if (!clientSocket.isClosed() && ServerSettings.getServerStatus() != -1) {
        // start communication
    } else {
        // close connection
    }
}
```

I looked for this issue and found [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully) to exit the loop. But this does not completely solve my problem. I can change the value of `finished` variable, but to check the new value I still need to skip the waiting once.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: As an aside: true && !finished == !finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) method. This will stop the wainting of connections.

Comment: So, do I need to throw the `SocketException` on click since it is waiting?

Comment: Yes. You should throw SocketException.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ServerSocket`, use `ServerSocketChannel`, it's `accept()` method does not block. From documentation:

> `public abstract SocketChannel accept() throws IOException`
>
> Accepts a connection made to this channel's socket.
>
> If this channel is in non-blocking mode then this method will immediately return null if there are no pending connections.