# Java Thread behaving synchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, volatile, synchronous

in the below piece of code when ever the while loop is empty it's going in an infinite loop as the flag updated by thread 2 isn't getting reflected

```
public class testing2 {
    private static boolean flag = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Thread 1: Toggles the flag value
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!flag) {
                //System.out.println("hello");
            }
            System.out.println("Flag is now true!");
        });

        // Thread 2: Changes the flag value after a delay
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Delay for 1 second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            flag = true;
            System.out.println("Flag has been set to true.");
        });

        // Start both threads
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

result : "Flag has been set to true." and continues running

but whenever i uncomment the code in while loop i'm getting below response

.
.
.
Hello
hello
hello
Flag has been set to true.
Flag is now true!

Kindly help me understand why is it behaving like this

i was trying to reproduce an error scenario

Comment: Try with  
`private static AtomicBoolean flag = false;`
instead of  
`private static boolean flag = false;`

Comment: Note that the original duplicate did not answer this question. The change in behavior that you describe is caused by synchronization around `println()`, detailed in the new duplicate post.

Comment: Another post worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25425130/217324

Comment: Beware: Output from `System.out.println` does *not* necessarily appear on the console in chronological order when called across threads. Always include and study a timestamp when you care about order: `Instant.now().toString()`. Or else collect your messages in a thread-safe collection. Or use a proper logging facility.

Comment: @KernelPanic Actually that should be `final`, and should pass `false` to a constructor. `private static final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean( false ) ;`

Comment: Better to delete the flag and have the thread use interruption, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3196058/217324